# Surprising behaviour when trying to prove a forall

Tags: triggers, z3, smt, quantifiers

Consider the following SMT-LIB code:

```
(set-option :auto_config false)
(set-option :smt.mbqi false)
; (set-option :smt.case_split 3)
(set-option :smt.qi.profile true)

(declare-const x Int)

(declare-fun trigF (Int Int Int) Bool)
(declare-fun trigF$ (Int Int Int) Bool)
(declare-fun trigG (Int) Bool)
(declare-fun trigG$ (Int) Bool)

; Essentially noise
(declare-const y Int)
(assert (!
  (not (= x y))
  :named foo
))

; Essentially noise
(assert (forall ((x Int) (y Int) (z Int)) (!
  (= (trigF$ x y z) (trigF x y z))
  :pattern ((trigF x y z))
  :qid |limited-F|
)))

; Essentially noise
(assert (forall ((x Int)) (!
  (= (trigG$ x) (trigG x))
  :pattern ((trigG x))
  :qid |limited-G|
)))

; This assumption is relevant
(assert (forall ((a Int) (b Int) (c Int)) (!
  (and
    (trigG a)
    (trigF a b c))
  :pattern ((trigF a b c))
  :qid |bar|
)))
```

Trying to assert that axiom `bar` holds, i.e.,

```
(push)
(assert (not (forall ((a Int) (b Int) (c Int))
  (and
    (trigG a)
    (trigF a b c)))))
(check-sat)
(pop)
```

fails (Z3 4.3.2 - build hashcode 47ac5c06333b):

```
unknown
[quantifier_instances]  limited-G :      1 :   0 : 1
```

**Question 1:** Why did Z3 only instantiate `limited-G` but neither `limited-F` nor `bar` (which would prove the assertion)?

**Question 2:** Commenting any of the (useless) assertions `foo`, `limited-F` or `limited-G` allows Z3 to prove the assertion - why is that? (Depending on which are commented, either only `bar` or `bar` and `limited-F` are instantiated.)

In case it is related to the observed behaviour: I would like to set `smt.case_split` to `3` (my configuration follows the one omitted by MSR's [Boogie](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/boogie/) tool), but Z3 gives me `WARNING: auto configuration (option AUTO_CONFIG) must be disabled to use option CASE_SPLIT=3, 4 or 5`, despite the fact that `(set-option :auto_config false)`.

Comment: No answer to your question yet, but there have been a number of bugfixes relating to parameter problems, which is also the source of the warning messages you see. Could you verify that the problem still exists?

Comment: @ChristophWintersteiger I just tried with Z3 4.4.0 9bff93279f75 x64 and the result is the same

Comment: @ChristophWintersteiger FYI: The official Z3 4.4.0 release (https://github.com/Z3Prover/bin/blob/master/releases/z3-4.4.0-x64-win.zip) still shows the same behaviour

Answer (score 3):

The situation is as follows:

- when using pattern based instantiation exclusively Z3 takes a somewhat operational approach to finding quantifier instantiations.
- by disabling MBQI you rely on the equality matching engine.
- case_split = 3 instructs Z3 to use relevancy heuristic when 
  choosing candidates for equality matching.
- The assert (not (forall (a, b, c) (and (trigG a) (trigF a b c)))) expands
  into a disjunction (or (not (trigG a!0)) (not (trigF a!0 b!1 c!2))).
- only one of the two disjuncts is relevant for satisfying the formula.
- The search sets (trigG a!0) to false, so the clause is satisfied. The trigger (trigF a b c) is therefore never activated.

You can bypass this issue by distributing in universal quantifiers over conjunctions, and supplying patterns in each case. Thus, you(r tool) could rewrite the axiom:

```
(assert (forall ((a Int) (b Int) (c Int)) (!
  (and
    (trigG a)
    (trigF a b c))
  :pattern ((trigF a b c))
  :qid |bar|
 )))
```

to the two axioms.

```
(assert (forall ((a Int)) (! (trigG a) :pattern ((trigG a))))
(assert (forall ((a Int) (b Int) (c Int)) (!
    (trigF a b c)
  :pattern ((trigF a b c))
  :qid |bar|
 )))
```

The issue of setting auto-completion seems fixed. I somewhat recently fixed bug in the way that some top-level configurations were reset if multiple top-level configurations were set in the smt-lib input.