# Why is E-matching for conjunctions sensitive to order / case-splitting strategy?

Tags: z3

Given the following simplified quantifiers, with the Z3 options set according to those generated by Boogie (full details below), I get "unknown" as a result:

```
(declare-fun F (Int) Bool)
(declare-fun G (Int) Bool)

(assert (forall ((x Int)) (! (and
  (F x) (G x))
  :pattern ((F x))
)))
(assert (not (forall ((x Int)) (! (and
  (G x) (F x))
  :pattern ((F x))
))))
(check-sat)
```

My understanding for what (I think) Z3 would do with this problem, is skolemise the existential (not forall), which would yield ground instances of both F and G. Given these in the e-graph, we should be able to instantiate the other quantifier, and get unsat. I can see that Z3 probably has to case-split to do this, but I would expect this case-splitting to take place after removing the quantifier and populating the e-graph.

Instead, the first quantifier doesn't get instantiated in the above problem. I've made a number of observations:

1. Swapping the order of the (F x) and (G x) terms in the first quantifier results in "unsat" without any quantifier instantiations (I suppose some simplification spots the similarity between the two quantified assertions?).
2. Swapping the order of the (G x) and (F x) terms in the second quantifier (as well as those in the first) results in "unsat" with a single quantifier instantiation (which is the behaviour I'd expect in general).
3. Changing the smt.case_split option affects the behaviour. Set to 3 (as chosen by Boogie) or 5, we get "unknown". Set to 0,1,2 or 4, I get "unsat".

It would be great to understand the scenarios above, and why (in the failing cases) these terms don't always make it to the e-graph after skolemisation. I'm not sure what the effects of changing the case_split option are in general. At the moment, I don't think Boogie allows that to be changed (and overrides any choice made on the command-line). But I have the feeling that the e-graph should get the information in all cases, ideally.

Here's the full file (removing most of the options set doesn't seem to make a difference to the failing cases, except for the smt.case_split one):

```
(set-option :print-success false)
(set-info :smt-lib-version 2.0)
(set-option :AUTO_CONFIG false)
;(set-option :MODEL.V2 true)
(set-option :smt.PHASE_SELECTION 0)
(set-option :smt.RESTART_STRATEGY 0)
(set-option :smt.RESTART_FACTOR |1.5|)
(set-option :smt.ARITH.RANDOM_INITIAL_VALUE true)
(set-option :smt.DELAY_UNITS true)
(set-option :NNF.SK_HACK true)
(set-option :smt.MBQI false)
(set-option :smt.QI.EAGER_THRESHOLD 100)
(set-option :smt.QI.COST |"(+ weight generation)"|)
(set-option :TYPE_CHECK true)
(set-option :smt.BV.REFLECT true)
(set-option :TIMEOUT 0)
(set-option :smt.QI.PROFILE true)
(set-option :smt.CASE_SPLIT 3)
; done setting options


(declare-fun F (Int) Bool)
(declare-fun G (Int) Bool)

(assert (forall ((x Int)) (! (and
  (F x) (G x))
   :pattern ((F x))
)))
(assert (not (forall ((x Int)) (! (and
(G x) (F x))
  :pattern ((F x))
))))
(check-sat)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is settled by the answer from https://stackoverflow.com/users/1096362/nikolaj-bjorner to this question:
[Surprising behaviour when trying to prove a forall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25622964/surprising-behaviour-when-trying-to-prove-a-forall)

The translation of the proof obligation into a disjunction, followed by corresponding relevancy of the clauses, explains why Z3 doesn't see both conjuncts as potential triggers.