# Puzzling (and fragile) result from e-matching-related SMT query

Tags: z3

For the following smt file (which has been minimised a lot from a Viper/Boogie-generated example) , Z3 returns `unknown` (very fast).

```
(set-option :print-success false)
(set-info :smt-lib-version 2.0)
(set-option :AUTO_CONFIG false)
(set-option :pp.bv_literals false)
(set-option :MODEL.V2 true)
(set-option :smt.PHASE_SELECTION 0)
(set-option :smt.RESTART_STRATEGY 0)
(set-option :smt.RESTART_FACTOR |1.5|)
(set-option :smt.ARITH.RANDOM_INITIAL_VALUE true)
(set-option :smt.CASE_SPLIT 3)
(set-option :smt.DELAY_UNITS true)
(set-option :NNF.SK_HACK true)
(set-option :smt.MBQI false)
(set-option :smt.QI.EAGER_THRESHOLD 100)
(set-option :TYPE_CHECK true)
(set-option :smt.BV.REFLECT true)
; (options as set by Boogie)

(declare-sort T@Seq 0)
(declare-fun Append (T@Seq T@Seq) T@Seq)
(declare-fun Empty () T@Seq)
(declare-fun Singleton (Int) T@Seq)
(declare-fun dummy () Bool)
(declare-fun Contains (T@Seq Int) Bool)
; Empty ++ s == s
(assert (forall ((s T@Seq) ) (! (= (Append Empty s) s)
 :qid |_0314cbp.11:15|
 :skolemid |0|
 :pattern ( (Append Empty s))
)))
; (strange axiom)
; forall s0,s1 :: {s0++s1} s0 != Empty ==> dummy
(assert (forall ((s0 T@Seq) (s1 T@Seq) ) (!  (=> (not (= s0 Empty)) dummy)
 :qid |_0314cbp.17:15|
 :skolemid |3|
 :pattern ( (Append s0 s1))
)))
; forall s0,s1,x :: {(Contains s0++s1 x)} Contains s0++s1 x <==> (Contains s0 x || Contains s1 x)
(assert (forall ((s0@@0 T@Seq) (s1@@0 T@Seq) (x Int) ) (!  (and (=>     (Contains (Append s0@@0 s1@@0) x) (or (Contains s0@@0 x) (Contains s1@@0 x))) (=> (or (Contains s0@@0 x) (Contains s1@@0 x)) (Contains (Append s0@@0 s1@@0) x)))
 :qid |_0314cbp.22:15|
 :skolemid |4|
 :pattern ( (Contains (Append s0@@0 s1@@0) x))
)))
(declare-fun s () T@Seq)
(declare-fun s1 () T@Seq) ; spurious term, used for assumption
(declare-fun i () Int)
(declare-fun f (Int) Bool)
(push 1)
(assert (not
; forall x_1 :: {(Contains s x_1)} f x_1
(=> (and (forall ((x_1 Int) ) (! (f x_1)
 :qid |_0314cbp.34:20|
 :skolemid |5|
 :pattern ( (Contains s x_1))
)) (= s1 (Append s (Singleton 1)))) (=> (Contains (Append s (Singleton 1)) i ) ( f i ))))
)
(check-sat)
(pop 1)
; Invalid
```

My understanding is that this result is expected; the only way to obtain `unsat` that I'm aware of, is to instantiate the last quantifier (inside the last `assert`ed formula), whose pattern is `(Contains s x_1)`. This term is not known in the context; what is possible is for the known `(Contains (Append s (Singleton 1)) i )` to cause the quantifier with `:qid |_0314cbp.22:15|` to be instantiated, which yields the disjunction `(or (Contains s i ) (Contains (Singleton 1) i))`. If/when Z3 branches on this disjunction, the former case will have the term to get `unsat` from the last axiom with, but the latter will not. As is [explained elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25622964/surprising-behaviour-when-trying-to-prove-a-forall), Z3 will backtrack the instantiations made between such case-splits.

What's surprising to me about the example is that many modifications can be made to it to obtain an `unsat` result, and these either weaken the logical assumptions made, or leave them unchanged; in each case I don't understand why the same reasoning as above would not apply to explain that `unknown` should be expected. For example:

1. The assumption `(= s1 (Append s (Singleton 1)))` is spurious; the term `s1` is not used anywhere else in the problem, and `(Append s (Singleton 1))` is a known term in the following implication (so its presence should not affect potential e-matching). However, removing it, or replacing it with `true` (i.e. weakening the assumptions made) will result in `unsat`.
2. Removing either of the first two quantifiers (the second of which has no logical meaning) will result in `unsat`.
3. Rewriting the third axiom to express an implication (`Contains s0++s1 x ==> (Contains s0 x || Contains s1 x)`) rather than an if-and-only-if will result in `unsat`.
4. Removing the `(push 1)` and `(pop 1)` will result in `unsat`.

My main question is, are these (changes of) behaviours expected, and how can I explain them? In addition, if there is a good way to see what Z3 does with the problem, and try to uncover more information for myself, I'd be happy to do so.

I have tried the example (and its variants) using the Axiom Profiler tool; there I was able to see that the same number of quantifier instantiations are made (3), but in the case of the axiom about distributing `Contains` over `Append`, sometimes a simplified term seems to be learned by Z3, rather than the full quantifier body. I can provide more details of this if they would be useful.